# VS Code - wsl server closed unexpectedly

Tags: bash, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

yesterday my laptop run out of battery it was late night and decided to not turn it on back.

In the morning I ran into this issue Could you help me please. Can't move forward in my developing course.

Thank you very much.

[image]

Comment: Just close VS code and reopen it using `code .` from the appropriate directory within a wsl session.

Answer (score 15):

Ohh, I found the solution :
go to `\\wsl$\Ubuntu-18.04\home\<userName>`
then remove `.vscode-server`

Go to the terminal and run `code .` command.

Comment: you saved my time and money! thanks

Answer (score 1):

This solves the problem! BUT...!!! I don't know the reason of this error, it happened to me after a VSCode update... however deleting .vscode-server folder solves the issue; but you must be aware that you will have to re-install ALL extensions on WSL because they'll be deleted as well.